# What is the variance of negative predictive value when sensitivity is 1?

Tags: binomial-distribution, sensitivity-specificity

Variance of NPV is calculated using (1-sensitivity).
If estimated( sensitivity) =1 then var(NPV)=0
Is there an alternative formula for var(NPV) similar to Score formula for sensitivity?

Comment: No, there isn't. For example, there are multiple methods of obtaining a sensitivity of 1, not the least of which is to select everything as positive.

Comment: @Carl I think this is close to being an answer - the answer is 'no'.

Comment: (+1) For asking a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. For example, there are multiple methods of obtaining a sensitivity of 1, not the least of which is to select everything as positive. For example, if the prevalence is 99 out of 100, and we detect the 99 positives by using 99 choices, the sensitivity is 1. However, if we select the 99 positives by choosing all 100 choices, then the sensitivity is still 1.

I think you want an answer to a different question, but, I am not sure which one since there are many.